# How do I create a bot to play games for me in python?

Tags: python, object-detection, pyautogui

For the specific game I want to make a bot for (Fnaf: Ultimate Custom Night) I want to have certain keys pressed when something pops up on the screen. For this i need to recognize the object on the screen, and then use something like pyautogui to click the button. I know how to do the second part, but I can't seem to figure out how to do the real time object recognition part on the screen. The only tutorials I can find online are object detection with webcams, or stuff like that but I can't find any with real time detection on your screen.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pyautogui
```

locateOnScreen should work with you by saving screenshots of the desired elements to click and run it in an infinite loop

example:

```
image = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('image2.png')
if image != None:
     pyautogui.click(image)
else:
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer above works, but if the object is slightly covered up, it won't work as it has to be an exact match. I would recommend installing OpenCV as it lets you:

```
import pyautogui
image = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('image2.png', confidence = 0.9)
if image != None:
     pyautogui.click(image)
else:
    pass
```

Notice that the 'confidence' argument is given as a decimal